# Possible bug in the front end: MapThread::mptd: Object FE`DynamicModuleVariableList

Tags: front-end

To reproduce this issue:

1. execute `?Grid*`, `?Plot*`, `?List*`, or similar
2. click on one of the possibilities

I see several error messages, all related to something called
`FE DynamicModuleVariableList`. (There's supposed to be a backtick right after `FE`, but I can't figure out the right escape sequence.)

This is on a recent MacBook Pro running Mathematica v.10 on OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows 10 running Mathematica 11.0.1. Details on your configuration (OS and Mathematica versions, etc..)? By the way, "\" escapes in the code snippets, I think: `test\`line`

Comment: @user6014: Escaping the backtick "\`" did not work for me in the main question. What about here: `test\`line`? That's bizarre! Why does that work here, but not above?

Comment: Something like this?: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=29260412#29260412

Comment: @ Kuba: Similar. Not identical. And, _Oh, this is frustrating!_ Before submitting a question to StackExchange, I tried to make sure I wasn't spamming the site: I killed the kernel and did my "`?Grid*`, click on one of the possibilities" test. Yep. Problem was repeatable. Now, after restarting Mathematica (not just the kernel), I can't reproduce the error.